# How to reset branch state to master while completely preserving branch history?

Tags: git, github

Essentially I want to reset my branch state to master without deleting its history and without appending the history of master. I want to reset state of the branch in a single commit.

Let's say `master` is in state A. And the `branch` is in state B. `master` has commits `<X1>`, `<X2>`, `<X3>`, ... , `<X(N-2)>`, `<X(N-1)>`, `<X(N)>`. `branch` has commits `<X(N-2+1)>`, `<X(N-2+2)>` because it was started when `master` was still at `<X(N-2)>`.

**(1)** I want `branch` to match state at `<X(N)>` without having `<X(N-2)>`, `<X(N-1)>`, `<X(N)>` appended onto my commit history. **(2)** Additionally, I want my diff for `branch` to show 0 files changed. I just want a new commit `<X(N-2+3)>` that completely replaces my branch state with `<X(N)>` state.

In order to do that I want to replace all my local changes with the `<X(N)>` state and push without --force. I haven't been able to find a solution online for this kind of thing without the side effects of **(1)** and **(2)** as well as having to force push which to me seems to dangerous.

Comment: Tag your current state and re-hang the branch label on the master state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... I suppose you could

```
git checkout branch
git rm -r :/:
git checkout master -- :/:
git add :/:
git commit -m "reset state to match master"
```

I'm not sure what you mean about the `diff`, but given that you've already described the target state, the `diff` is a given - it's going to be the difference between the state you described, and whatever you're comparing against with `diff`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a diff between `branch` and `master`, and apply that as one single commit onto `branch`:

```
git diff --binary HEAD..master | git apply --index
```

This updates the working directory and the index. You can then `git commit` the new state.